# How to consolidate arrays under one single MultiLineString GeoJSON array using jq?

Tags: json, geojson, jq

There are coordinates within an array that are divided up between multiple GeoJSON `MultiLineString` structures. I would like to consolidate all the coordinates, maintaining them in their own array, under one single MultiLineString structure. How do i do this with `jq` ?

This is the original file (modified for example purposes)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },

  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.619152670413143, 29.568340757283536, 0.0],
            [-82.619147188198966, 29.568355832670516, 0.0],
            [-82.607558975018591, 29.580299204829011, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.619152670413513, 29.568340757283536, 0.0],
            [-82.619490683489488, 29.568318912277654, 0.0],
            [-82.629348688631055, 29.569000553128618, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.629348688631055, 29.569000553128618, 0.0],
            [-82.62943243076478, 29.568922074598046, 0.0],
            [-82.623065167913538, 29.56611193045412, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.618039923193663, 29.563657436904819, 0.0],
            [-82.618306111861301, 29.565336028000189, 0.0],
            [-82.619152670413669, 29.568340757283639, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.62306516791385, 29.566111930454156, 0.0],
            [-82.618758856449034, 29.563742939021793, 0.0],
            [-82.618212862210015, 29.563577318475456, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What I am trying to achieve:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },

  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiLineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [-82.619152670413143, 29.568340757283536, 0.0],
            [-82.619147188198966, 29.568355832670516, 0.0],
            [-82.607558975018591, 29.580299204829011, 0.0]
          ],
          [
            [-82.619152670413513, 29.568340757283536, 0.0],
            [-82.619490683489488, 29.568318912277654, 0.0],
            [-82.629348688631055, 29.569000553128618, 0.0]
          ],
          [
            [-82.629348688631055, 29.569000553128618, 0.0],
            [-82.62943243076478, 29.568922074598046, 0.0],
            [-82.623065167913538, 29.56611193045412, 0.0]
          ],
          [
            [-82.618039923193663, 29.563657436904819, 0.0],
            [-82.618306111861301, 29.565336028000189, 0.0],
            [-82.619152670413669, 29.568340757283639, 0.0]
          ],
          [
            [-82.62306516791385, 29.566111930454156, 0.0],
            [-82.618758856449034, 29.563742939021793, 0.0],
            [-82.618212862210015, 29.563577318475456, 0.0]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to a simple solution is to recognize that the combined "coordinates" array can be computed by the filter:

```
[.features[] | .geometry | .coordinates[]]
```

which can be abbreviated as:

```
[.features[].geometry.coordinates[]]
```

Let's call this array `$combined`.  A solution can then be obtained by updating `.features`, like so:

```
.features = [.features[0] | (.geometry.coordinates = $combined)]
```

A complete solution is thus:

```
[.features[].geometry.coordinates[]] as $combined
| .features = [.features[0] | (.geometry.coordinates = $combined)]
```

This can be further simplified using the `|=` operator:

```
[.features[].geometry.coordinates[]] as $combined
| .features |= [.[0] | (.geometry.coordinates = $combined)]
```

Comment: So, do I understand this solution correctly that `.features = [.features[0]]` takes the first instance and basically uses it as a template for the new structure, and then `(.geometry.coordinates = $combined)` updates that structure's coordinates with the entire set of the original coordinates?

Comment: Not OP, just curious. Anyway, slick solution.

Comment: That's what the OP seemed to be asking for.

Comment: @gregory Nice. Thank you for the solution. I've posted it to https://jqplay.org/s/ziF_aBLdbQ
Quick follow-up question, how do I tell jq to maintain coordinates structure on the same line instead of putting the lat, long and z-axis on separate lines within the array?

Comment: In other words, can jq output this way: https://regex101.com/r/EIoyOt/1 ?

Comment: @HagbardCeline credit Peak, not me. Anyway, string interpolation could be used to reformat the array. I'd ask that in another question.

Comment: @HagbardCeline ...or just pipe to sed to remove newlines and extra spaces, e.g. on my Mac:  `sed -E -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/([0-9],)\n/\1/g' -e 's/(,)([[:blank:]]+)/\1 /g' ` does the trick.

Comment: @peak thank you for your solution! 
@gregory thank you for the additional help (though the sed didn't totally fix the issue and I'm having a hard time deciphering sed syntax. I was hoping it was possible to format the output using `jq` itself.

Comment: Figured out how to use Perl PCRE regex to get the formatting result I needed: `perl -0 -lpe 's/\[\n\s*(.*,)\n\s*(.*)\s*\]/[ $1 $2 ]/mg'`